# Fade in chain animations don't work: only view fades in

Tags: swift, animation, fade, uianimation

I'm trying to use a fade in animation chain to fade in my objects in order. First I make the view fade in, then the rest of the labels should follow suit. The labels are in a stack view, which has an alpha of `1.0`. I made sure that all of the other alpha values started at zero. Here is my function:

```
func fadeIn() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: { finished in
        if finished {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.gameOverLabel.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: { finished in
                if finished {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                        self.scoreLabel.alpha = 1.0
                    }, completion: { finished in
                        if finished {
                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                                self.highScoreLabel.alpha = 1.0
                            }, completion: { finished in
                                if finished {
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                                        self.restartButton.alpha = 1.0
                                    }, completion: nil)
                                    //breakpoint set here
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I set a breakpoint after all of the animations were completed(as shown above) and all alpha values were `1.0`. However, the device just gives me a blank, white screen. What is going on?

P.S. The function is called immediately after this view controller is presented:

```
view.present(vc, animated: false, completion: {
    vc.fadeIn()
})
```

Comment: You may need to put this animation operation in the presented view's `viewDidAppear`. I think animation operations might be invalid until it's been called, and `completion` on the `present` function might happen before that.

Comment: @jake Thanks for the suggestion. I put this function call in the `viewDidAppear` but it still showed the same white screen. For some reason, only the view's alpha gets animated to 1.

Comment: I'm confused. You said at the breakpoint "all alpha values were were `1.0`" so what you're saying is - everything after the first animation isn't getting called?

Comment: @jake That's exactly the issue. The objects aren't showing up on the screen even though all of the alpha values are `1.0`. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: If that's the case then I'm stumped since I can't recreate this issue. My only advice is make sure you aren't changing the `alpha` values or setting `isHidden` anywhere (also, you could consider using keyframes in place of this callback hell).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `.layoutSubviews` option to your animations. Like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.layoutSubviews, animations: {
    // animate here
})
```

From apple's docs this option does this:

> Lay out subviews at commit time so that they are animated along with their parent.

Might be that the subviews aren't laid out yet at commit time due to being presented.